# Laravel 9 - Sorting Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have the given table structure:

```
// table: examples
+ -- + ---- +
| id | name |
+ -- + ---- +
| 1  | Test |
| 2  | Test |
+ -- + ---- +

// table: example_data
+ -- + --------------- + ------------------ + --- + ----------------- +
| id | example_data_id | exmaple_data_type  | key         | value     |
+ -- + --------------- + ------------------ + ------------|---------- +
| 1  | 1               | App\Models\Example | external    | 1         |
| 2  | 1               | App\Models\Example | otherKey    | string    |
| 3  | 2               | App\Models\Example | external    | 0         |
+ -- + --------------- + ------------------ + ----------- + --------- +
```

```
// Example Model:
public function daten()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(ExampleData::class, 'example_data');
    }

// ExampleData Model:
 public function example_data()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

How I can order my examples by "value" in "example_data" with key = "external"?

```
$examples = Example::with('daten')
                    ->orderBy(***value from external in daten***)  // something like this 'Example->daten->key="external" ==> orderBy Example->daten->value'
                    ->paginate($request->total);
```

Is it possible with orderBy and callback? How is the callback?

Comment: What is the orderBy criteria? like `example_data_id`? or `ExampleData->column`

Comment: ExampleData->column -- In ExampleData "value" column with column "key" == "external"

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question:

```
$examples = Example::with(['daten' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('key', 'asc');
    }])
    ->paginate($request->total);
```

This will order the `key` column by ascending.
If you want only records where `key` is equal to `external` you can do this:

```
$examples = Example::with(['daten' => function($query) {
        $query->where('key', 'external');
        $query->orderBy('value', 'desc');
    }])
    ->paginate($request->total);
```

And sort it by the `value` column.

Comment: Sorry, that not help. I will order $examples complete. That order "daten" subarray in $examples.